# не могу понять,почему не выводится ошибка когда обрабатываю в цикле..Помогите

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $user = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['user']));
        $family = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['family']));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
        $login = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login']));
        $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']));

        $form = array($user,$family,$email,$login,$password);


        foreach($form as $s => &$value){
            if($value = ""){
                echo 'Заполните поле!!!';
            }
        }


        include("../bd.php");

        $res=mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' ");
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($res);
            if(!empty($data['login'])){
                die("Такой логин уже существует!");
            }

        $password = hash('sha1', $password.$login);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user`,`family`,`email`,`login`,`pass`) 
                  VALUES('$user','$family','$email','$login','$password') ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result == true){
            echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <br><a href='../index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
        }else{
            echo "Error! ----> ". mysql_error();
        }*/
    }
?>
```

Comment: когда пустая строка

Comment: А зачем амперсанд? `foreach($form as $s => $value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach($form as $s => $value){
        if($value == ""){
            echo 'Заполните поле!!!';
        }
    }
```

Update:

---

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['user']));
    $family = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['family']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
    $login = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login']));
    $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']));

    $form = array($user,$family,$email,$login,$password);

    $exist = true;
    //начинаем проверку...
    foreach($form as $s => $value){
        if($value == ""){
            $exist=false;
        }
    }

if($exist){
  echo "Пустых полей не было..";
    include("../bd.php");

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' ");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if(!empty($data['login'])){
            die("Такой логин уже существует!");
        }

    $password = hash('sha1', $password.$login);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user`,`family`,`email`,`login`,`pass`) 
              VALUES('$user','$family','$email','$login','$password') ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result == true){
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <br><a href='../index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    }else{
        echo "Error! ----> ". mysql_error();
    }*/
}
else{
    echo 'Заполните поле!!!';
}
}
```

Comment: всё равно регистрирует

Comment: блин не так ввел...всё работает...бли надо было сравнивать,а я приствоил

Comment: @СашаВодяницкий работать то работает) и ошибку выводит, в чем и был Ваш вопрос. А вот то что Вы прогоняя цикл проверки на пустые значения просто выводите сообщение, то ни что не мешает циклу выполнятся дальше, и соответственно регистрация проходит

Comment: да...а как запретить тогда?подскажи

Comment: @СашаВодяницкий Обновил ответ

Comment: все равно регистрирует  так

Comment: @СашаВодяницкий я обновил ответ. Попробуйте новый код и скажите или `Пустых полей не было..` выведет на экран.

Comment: когда есть пустая строка выводит вы зарегистрированы

Comment: @СашаВодяницкий Потому что MikielD пошутил и сделал правку слегка неправильно, поправил

Comment: все спасибо всем!!!!вопрос закрыт!!

Comment: @СашаВодяницкий, Ну раз такое дело, то пометьте правильный ответ на ваш вопрос ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$error = false;    
foreach($form as $s => $value){
    if($value == ""){
        echo 'Заполните поле!!!';
        $error = true;
        //break; //можно раскоментировать брейк, чтобы дальше цикл не шел
    }
}
if ($error) return;
```

либо, если дальше нужно что-то выполнять, то:

```
if (!$error) {    
    include("../bd.php");


    $res=mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' ");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if(!empty($data['login'])){
            die("Такой логин уже существует!");
        }

    $password = hash('sha1', $password.$login);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user`,`family`,`email`,`login`,`pass`) 
              VALUES('$user','$family','$email','$login','$password') ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result == true){
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <br><a href='../index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    }else{
        echo "Error! ----> ". mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Весь код будет:

```
$error = false;    
foreach($form as $s => $value){
    if($value == ""){
        echo 'Заполните поле!!!';
        $error = true;
        //break; //можно раскоментировать брейк, чтобы дальше цикл не шел
    }
}
if (!$error) {    
        include("../bd.php");


    $res=mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' ");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if(!empty($data['login'])){
            die("Такой логин уже существует!");
        }

    $password = hash('sha1', $password.$login);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user`,`family`,`email`,`login`,`pass`) 
              VALUES('$user','$family','$email','$login','$password') ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result == true){
        echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! <br><a href='../index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
    }else{
        echo "Error! ----> ". mysql_error();
    }
}
```